# Aucun / aucun des / aucun d'entre les / personne des / personne d'entre les gardiens ne se souviendra

Tags: pronoms

Bonjour,

> Avec un peu de chance, **aucun** gardien ne se souviendra de deux pauvres
> gardes qui sont sortis pour faire une ronde et ne sont pas revenus.
>
> Avec un peu de chance, **aucun des** gardiens ne se souviendra de deux
> pauvres gardes qui sont sortis pour faire une ronde et ne sont pas
> revenus.
>
> Avec un peu de chance, **aucun d'entre** les gardiens ne se souviendra de
> deux pauvres gardes qui sont sortis pour faire une ronde et ne sont
> pas revenus.
>
> Avec un peu de chance, **personne des** gardiens ne se souviendra de deux
> pauvres gardes qui sont sortis pour faire une ronde et ne sont pas
> revenus.
>
> Avec un peu de chance, **personne d’entre** les gardiens ne se souviendra
> de deux pauvres gardes qui sont sortis pour faire une ronde et ne sont
> pas revenus.

Toutes les phrases sont correctes, n'est-ce pas ?

Comment: personne d'entre les gardiens?? gardiens et gardes?

Comment: @Lambie Oui, ce sont synonymes, merci.

Answer (score 4):

Correctes, oui, mais seules les deux premières (*aucun* et *aucun des*) sont des formes usuelles.

Après *aucun d'entre*, on trouve rarement autre chose que l'un des trois pronoms *nous*, *vous* et *eux* (+ *aucune d'entre elles*).

*Personne des xxx* est rare sauf peut-être comme complément: *Je n'ai vu personne des gardiens*.

*Personne d'entre* est comme *aucun d'entre*, généralement suivi d'un pronom pluriel.

Comme indiqué par Lambie en commentaire, on peut aussi rencontrer l'expression similaire : *personne, parmi les gardiens, ne se souviendra [...]*.

Pour ce qui est du conflit potentiel entre *gardes* et *gardiens*, s'il s'agit du même groupe de personnes, tu peux tourner ta phrase comme ceci :

> Avec un peu de chance, aucun des gardes/gardiens (restants) ne se souviendra des deux d'entre eux sortis faire une ronde sans être revenus.

Comment: Personne *parmi* les gardiens, serait pareil que: Aucun gardien. Ce personne d'entre x pluriel me fait mal aux dents.

Comment: @Lambie *Me fait mal aux dents* ?? Personne d'entre nous ne dirait ça !

Comment: @jlliagre ahahahahaha

Comment: Contente pour vous... En particulier, pour vous, @Michel T :(  À quoi elle sert, votre remarque ?...

Comment: @oreste A marquer qu'il a compris l'humour de mon commentaire. Rien de méchant la dedans.

Comment: A chacun ses sensibilités, n'est-ce pas?

Comment: @Lambie Oui, il y en a qui sont sensibles des oreilles et d'autres qui sont sensibles des dents ;-)

Comment: Tu trouves que gardien et garde sont synonymes dans les phrases données par le OP? Comment se fait-il que t'as rien dit au sujet de cette sémantique bizarroïde?

Comment: @Lambie Parce que ce n'était pas le sujet de la question. Même si c'est peu probable, on peut imaginer un contexte avec des gardes et des gardiens "disjoints".

Comment: Je comprends, mais justement je ne trouve pas drôle ton commentaire. Ni l'autre d'ailleurs. Peut-être que, qui sait ? à ma place tu ne l'aurais pas trouvé drôle non plus. Mais j'arrête là.

Comment: @Lambie Tu parles de "mal aux dents" ? C'était effectivement très surprenant, je ne sais toujours pas pourquoi tu as écrit ça. On l'aurait dit en anglais, *it hurts my theeth* ? La phrase suivante n'était qu'un exemple pour montrer que l'expression *personne d'entre + pluriel* est bien vivante. Je faisais d'une pierre deux coups. J'aurais certainement trouvé drôle ce genre de réponse si on me l'avait faite à moi-même.

Comment: Il se trouve que souvent les questions sont mal posées. A mon avis, avant d'expliquer quoi que ce soit, il vaut mieux bien écrire la chose. Non, en anglais it makes my teeth hurt n'est pas une expression toute faite. J'aurai pu dire: Cela me donne mal à la tête. Cela me fait mal aux oreilles. Tout ça pour dire que la tournure avec entre et gardes et gardiens dans la même phrase me fait "souffrir corporellement" (presque).  C'était pour faire rire. On m'a dit (lá-haut) qu'ils sont synonymes. Alors là, il est temps de faire ses valises.

Comment: @Lambie Comme c'était pour faire rire, tu aurais pu mettre un smiley mais je peux me faire le même reproche à moi-même, puisque je n'ai pas mis non plus de smiley à mon premier commentaire. Je ne savais pas trop si ton deuxième commentaire n'était pas d'ailleurs un trait d'humour (sensibilité des dents vs sensibilité des oreilles). Garde et gardien sont souvent spécialisés et non interchangeables mais les deux peuvent sortir faire une ronde.

Comment: réf: « D'en mal parler fait grincer la démangeaison... ». Massacrer le nom de [Faʁdɔʃ](https://youtu.be/G4Dd_PXu-tU)ɔtɔmatabaʁwɛt de même, nom de tabourette !

Comment: "Synonymes" ne veut pas nécessairement dire "toujours interchangeables"...

Comment: Oui, bien sûr. Il ne doit pas y avoir beaucoup de synonymes qui sont parfaitement interchangeables.

Comment: mais on ne sait toujours pas si les deux gardes qui sont partis pour ne pas revenir faisaient partie du groupe des gardiens dont on parle dans la phrase ou pas.